# Conflict between rule 18 and token ADD resolved as reduce (ADD < UMINUS)

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I write a grammatical analysis with bison. I definded some priority rules like:

```
%right EQUAL
%left OR AND
%left ADD SUB
%left MUL DIV MOD
%nonassoc UMINUS
```

then I use them like:

```
math
: math ADD math {$$ = math_add($1,$3);}
| math OR math {$$ = math_or($1,$3);}
| math AND math {$$ = math_and($1,$3);}
| math SUB math {$$ = math_sub($1,$3);}
| math MUL math {$$ = math_mul($1,$3);}
| math DIV math {$$ = math_div($1,$3);}
| math MOD math {$$ = math_mod($1,$3);}
| SUB math %prec UMINUS {$$ = math_unary_uminus($2);}
| PARENTHESIS math CLOSE_PARENTHESIS {$$ = $2;}
| literal {$$ =$1;}
| reference {$$ = $1;}
```

Run ,It will generate a .output file contains some conflicts:

```
state 33 
11 math: math . ADD math
12     | math . OR math
13     | math . AND math
14     | math . SUB math
15     | math . MUL math
16     | math . DIV math
17     | math . MOD math
18     | SUB math .  [ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD, OR, AND, CLOSE_PARENTHESIS]

 $default  reduce using rule 18 (math)

 Conflict between rule 18 and token ADD resolved as reduce (ADD < UMINUS).
 Conflict between rule 18 and token SUB resolved as reduce (SUB < UMINUS).
 Conflict between rule 18 and token MUL resolved as reduce (MUL < UMINUS).
 Conflict between rule 18 and token DIV resolved as reduce (DIV < UMINUS).
 Conflict between rule 18 and token MOD resolved as reduce (MOD < UMINUS).
 Conflict between rule 18 and token OR resolved as reduce (OR < UMINUS).
 Conflict between rule 18 and token AND resolved as reduce (AND < UMINUS).
```

I can't resolve it, please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you ran `bison` with the `-r all` option (or `--report=all`) which includes the `solved` report ("describe shift/resolve conflicts solving"). So that's what it's doing: it's describing how it solved the shift/resolve conflict by using the precedence rules you supplied.

In other words, there is no problem.